# Select children of element that does not have a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to select all the ul.menu within the li's (submenu's) that don't have an "active-trail" class

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li class="expanded">item 2
         <ul class="menu">
             <li>sub item a</li>
             <li>sub item b</li>
             <li>sub item c</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">item 3
         <ul class="menu">
             <li>sub item d</li>
             <li>sub item e</li>
             <li>sub item f</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded active-trail">item 4
         <ul class="menu">
             <li>sub item g</li>
             <li>sub item h</li>
             <li>sub item i</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#region-menu ul.menu > li.expanded:not:has(active-trail) ul.menu ').addClass('hidden')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
$('li.expanded:not(.active-trail) ul.menu').addClass('hidden');
```

You were close, but the selector you need inside `:not()` is the class `.active-trail`

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMRAq/)**

Answer (score 2):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4CyM/1/)**

```
$('ul.menu > li.expanded:not(.active-trail) ul.menu ').addClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$("li.expanded ul").parent(':not(.active-trail)')
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4LYF/1/)